# Dynamically Added Checkboxes Shows Only Last Value

Tags: android

Here is my code that results in only last value of Employee List

```
 public void addCheckBoxesView()
     {
         Employee ee;
         CheckBox chkbox;
         ArrayList<Employee> employee_list= initEmployees();
         for(int i =0; i<employee_list.size();i++)
         {
             ee = (Employee) employee_list.get(i);
             chkbox = new CheckBox(this);
             chkbox.setId(ee.getID());
             chkbox.setText(ee.getName());
             layout.addView(chkbox);
         }
     }
```

Comment: you may want to post the linear layout or xml in which you are adding the dynamic values.

Comment: LinearLyout @vikas kumar

Comment: if you are adding it in the vertical linear layout then it should not be any problem in the horizontal linear layout the dynamically added values may get out of bounds.

Comment: vertical layout

Comment: and here by value what do you mean then?. what is not showing the widget or the value you are setting on widget

Comment: ArrayList<Employee> has 6 Employee Objects but it displays only single last Object Values

Comment: @user3419496 try my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Try this`

Layout file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_root"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.xml

```
    LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_root);
    LinearLayout sublayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    sublayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


    Employee ee;
    CheckBox chkbox;
    ArrayList<Employee> employee_list = new ArrayList<>();
    Employee employee=new Employee();
    employee.setId(1);
    employee.setName("as");
    employee_list.add(employee);

    Employee bb=new Employee();
    bb.setId(4);
    bb.setName("siva");
    employee_list.add(bb);


    Employee hsud=new Employee();
    hsud.setId(16);
    hsud.setName("kumar");
    employee_list.add(hsud);


    for (int i = 0; i < employee_list.size(); i++) {
        ee = (Employee) employee_list.get(i);
        chkbox = new CheckBox(this);
        chkbox.setId(ee.getId());
        chkbox.setText(ee.getName());
        sublayout.addView(chkbox);
    }
    rootLayout.addView(sublayout);
```

Employee.xml

```
    class Employee {
        int id;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        String name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below if it works.

```
public void addCheckBoxesView()
     {
         ArrayList<Employee> employee_list= initEmployees();
         for(Employee ee : employee_list)
         {
             CheckBox chkbox = new CheckBox(this);
             chkbox.setId(ee.getID());
             chkbox.setText(ee.getName());
             layout.addView(chkbox);
         }
     }
```