# Trouble creating LinearLayout dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, dynamically-generated

Im trying to dynamically create a LinearLayout with a number of TextViews just the way it is described in several posts on this forum.

```
    LinearLayout llTest = new LinearLayout(this);

    for(int i=0; i<20; i++){

        TextView tvLine = new TextView(this);
        llTest.addView(tvLine);

        tvLine.setText("Text");
    }
```

Unfortunately it never displays anything but a blank screen, no matter what I tried so far with different methods. Ive tried setting the LayoutParams to various values, setOrientation, setGravity etc. I have made an application using a fairly complex TableLayout successfully but in this the TableLayout was created in XML, only the TableRows and the TextViews were created dynamically.

Whats my basic error here?

Comment: you will also have to give llTest layout params and add it to the view of the activity.

Comment: 1) are you adding the `LinearLayout` to your root `View`? 2) you should set `LayoutParams` for dinamically create views 3) for what you're doing it would be much cleaner to use a `RecyclerView`

Comment: try like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47930316/3505534

Comment: As I said I tried various LayoutParams with no success.

Comment: @ lelloman how do I add the LinearLayout to root view?

Comment: @ SAM this one creates the LinearLayout in XML, I want to do it dynamically in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this example

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 //Creating LinearLayout.
 LinearLayout linearlayout = new LinearLayout(this);

 //Setting up LinearLayout Orientation
 linearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

 LayoutParams linearlayoutlayoutparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 

 setContentView(linearlayout, linearlayoutlayoutparams);

 LayoutParams LayoutParamsview = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

 //Creating textview .
 TextView SampleTextView1 = new TextView(this);
 TextView SampleTextView2 = new TextView(this);

 //Adding text to TextView.
 SampleTextView1.setText("First TextView Text");
 SampleTextView2.setText("Second TextView Text");

 //Setting TextView text Size 
 SampleTextView1.setTextSize(25);
 SampleTextView2.setTextSize(25);

 SampleTextView1.setLayoutParams(LayoutParamsview);
 SampleTextView2.setLayoutParams(LayoutParamsview);

 //Adding textview to linear layout using Add View function.
 linearlayout.addView(SampleTextView1);
 linearlayout.addView(SampleTextView2);

 }
}
```

Comment: Ah, the missing part was the setContentView thingy. Thanks!

Comment: My original intention was however to create something like a popup window and delete it when ok'ed. I guess it wont work this way. I think I'll try creating the LinearLayout in XML and make it invisible until it's needed.